# Multiple open and close curly brackets inside method. - Java

Tags: java

```
 public class MyTestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyTestClass().myMethod();
    }

    public void myMethod(){
        {
        //do something 
        }
        {
            //do something 
        }
        {
            //do something 
        }
    }//method close

}//class close
```

What is the benefit of doing this? I have seen this kind of code.

Comment: This question was [referenced on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311442/opinion-based-questions-are-closed-what-about-opinion-based-answers).

Comment: I would suspect that this might be something inherited from C programmers. In the oldest version of the C standard, you could only declare variables on top of a block. So if you just wanted a temporary local variable (for example inside a switch-case), you would have to create a local block within the local block. This practice is obsolete in modern C, but you still see it now and then.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not common practice to do this kind of thing, and I wouldn't do it normally.

They are defined as Blocks in the JLS, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block).

Those inner blocks ( i.e. `{ ... }` ) can serve a couple of purposes:

- Blocks limit the scope of any variables declared within them; e.g.

  ```
  public void foo() {
      int i = 1;
      { 
          int j = 2;
      }
      // Can't refer to the "j" declared here.  But can declare a new one.
      int j = 3;
  }
  ```

  However, I wouldn't recommend doing this. IMO, it's better to use different variable names OR refactor the code into smaller methods.  Either way, most Java programmers would regard the `{` and `}` as annoying visual clutter.
- Blocks can be used to attach labels.

  ```
  HERE : {
      ...
      break HERE;  // breaks to the statement following the block
      ...
  }
  ```

  However, in practice you hardly ever see labelled break statements.  And because they are so unusual, they tend to render the code less readable.

Comment: Labelled statements are awful. I concur those shouldn't be used. Stick to more appropriate methods of splitting your code in parts.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void stuff() {
  int i = 48;

  { 
    int i = 21;
    System.out.println(i); // prints 21
  }
  System.out.println(i); // prints 48
}
```

Basically, it's a way to create scopes smaller than entire function... Benefit?.. have the people stare at your code longer before they understand it... IMO it's bad style and should be avoided

Comment: This is being used in one of the Hibernate framework class "AnnotationBinder.java"

Comment: Yeah, and that class is 2,000+ lines long, and it has individual methods of 600+ lines, and it has methods that take upwards of 10 parameters, and it barely has any Javadocs... I wouldn't emulate that

Comment: This is not correct in Java. You cannot redeclare a variable.

Comment: the code is in error and the compiler will issue an error: in Java you can't redeclare a local variable in a nested scope.